# How to load PHP's oci/pdo_oci modules in windows?

Tags: php, oracle, php-extension, instantclient

I am using PHP 5.4.28 as downloaded from windows.php.net. I am using the threadsafe version. I have also tried 32bit and 64bit Windows7 and I get the same results.

I have installed the oracle instantclient and have set/created the following system variables: ORACLE_HOME, PATH and TNS_ADMIN. These variables are definitely pointing to the correct folder. I've also copied all the dll files that came with instantclient to system32.

I still cannot make the oci drivers to load.

some notes:

1. extension_dir is properly set. I can load other modules like bz2
2. oci/pdo_oci drivers are present in extension_dir

Thanks for the help

Comment: do you have remove ";" in front of the extension?
`;extension=php_oci8.dll`
become
`extension=php_oci8.dll`
You can found it on php.ini file

Comment: yes.  I have removed the comment. as can be seen by note 1, I can load bz2.